How is the に particle used with a noun? にnounを?
In  a novel I was reading I found this passage

右腕を抱き、ため息に体をしぼませた。

The context is not that complicate, as the character arrives in a new home and it's tired so he does this.
What I'm confused, is what to make of the に here? I understand 体をしぼませた。 is "My body deflates/sags" but how is the sentence interacting with ため息?

Not め息 but ため息.

If I'm not mistaken, this is just the sentence structure "Agent に subject を passive verb". For example, "弟にケーキを食べられた" (The cake was eaten by my little brother).
In your case, I'd say that "ため息に体をしぼませた" basically means "his body deflated due to a sigh", or more naturally, "his body deflated with a sigh".

しぼませる is not a passive form.

@naruto you're right. I think I meant "transitive form", not passive.

@chausies the most common term is "causative" I think.
